# Conditional Comparison Operator Not Working With Snippet

Tags: ifelse, snippets, comparison

I am trying to get a snippet that calculates a value and compare the result to a number - the value is correctly outputted from my snippet when I include the var by itself. However when I use the snippet in a comparison if statement it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
{if total-positive-votes > 5} true {/if}
```

My snippet:

```
{exp:math_plus calculate="{var2}-({var1} - {var2})" var1="{overall_count}" var2="{overall_sum}"}
   {math_plus_result}
{/exp:math_plus}
```

Which outputs the following numbers correctly (each comma is a would be comparison):

```
0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 41, 8
```

So my comparison statement should output true on 41 and 8 but nothing comes back. Any one know why this isn't working? The funny thing is it used to work but I didn't use or upgrade this site for 2 years and it broke without me changing anything. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, `total-positive-votes` is your snippet.

I think you're over complicating things, since there's a pack of [mathematical operators](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#mathematic-operators) that can be used on conditionals.

```
{if overall_sum - (overall_count - overall_sum) > 5}
  true
{/if}
```

Or, to keep it even simpler, because multiplications always happen before sum, anyway:

```
{if 2 * overall_sum - overall_count > 5}
  true
{/if}
```

Comment: I am on version 2.5 - I guess I should upgrade to 2.10 because the new built in operators are bound to help!